# Есть вот такой код, он выводит числа где сумма первых трех совпадает с суммой последних трех. Как мне вывести количество таких чисел?

Tags: java

```
public class tram {
public static void main(String [] args) {



    int[] hl = new int[40];
    int[] ah = new int[40];
    int[] a  = new int[40];
    int[] b  = new int[40];
    int[] c  = new int[40];
    int[] d  = new int[40];
    int[] e  = new int[40];
    int[] f  = new int[40];


    for (int i=0; i < 40; ++i) {
        a[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
        b[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
        c[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
        d[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
        e[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
        f[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 8) + 1);


        hl[i] = a[i] + b[i] + c[i];
        ah[i] = d[i] + e[i] + f[i];


        if(hl[i] == ah[i]){
            System.out.println(a[i]+""+b[i]+""+c[i]+""+d[i]+""+e[i]+""+f[i]);
        } 



    }



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Вам лучше использовать двумерные массивы и не усложнять себе жизнь. 
2 - Что бы посчитать их, добавьте счётчик переменную. И инкрементируйте её в условии

```
if(hl[i] == ah[i]){
    count++;
    System.out.println(a[i]+""+b[i]+""+c[i]+""+d[i]+""+e[i]+""+f[i]);
}
```

Ну и выводите count*6 (на 6 так как у вас по 6 чисел совпадать должны)

Comment: Это что то не то. Я имею в виду, что когда выводит вот эти числа:
    661733
961376
452353

То есть выводит трижды, как это в коде прописать что оно трижды выводит?

Comment: Ну? Вам нужно количество выводимых на экран чисел?

Comment: " выводит числа где сумма первых трех совпадает с суммой последних трех. ", "количество таких чисел" 
Все правильно, если же вы выводите в цикле по 6 чисел, то и умножать нужно количество выводов на экран на 6

Comment: да, я вставлял до этого counter++ ну и он просто выводит единицу

Comment: для начала при объявлении присвойте ему 0, потом именно В УСЛОВИИ делаете с++
А сам счётчик выводите ВНЕ цикла, и УМНОЖАЕТЕ его на 6